# Inserting values into knockout viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to learn knockout. I am wanting to build an input form that inserts into a list

I have taken the examples and tried to modify them to suit.

I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spnz/DQGYX/1) example

I am wanting to setup the 2 textboxes to allow inserting values into the viewmodel. I have tried adding data-bind="value:question" & data-bind="value:qtype" to each of the inputs however that doesn't seem to help

If anyone could take a look at the jsfiddle and let me know what I am doing wrong would be awesome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the input elements to observables (or another variable) to capture them and then add them to the array. Fiddle is attached:

http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/DQGYX/7/

Answer (score 0):

You would likely want to add observables for `question` and `qtype` on your root view model.  Then, you can bind your inputs against them.

When you push to your list of questions, then you would read the values of the observables and finally clear them, so you are ready for the next input.

Here is an updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/DQGYX/4/